# Angular - PHP (VSCode) : php : The term 'php' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: php, node.js, angular, mongodb, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run my php file on VSCode and even after adding the path to the environment variables. It still shows

```
 `php : The term 'php' is not recognized as the name 
    of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable  
    program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
    path was included, verify that the path is correct   
    and try again.
    At line:1 char:1
    + php -S 0.0.0.0:1234
    + ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (php:  
   String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundExcept  
   ion`
```

Xampp's server is also turned on still it shows the same error again and again, please help me resolve this. Attaching the screenshot of the same below.

[Error Image along side Angular server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzYkw.png)

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall composer and set the PHP path once again in composer then check it once again. don't forget to repone the command prompt.
this works fine for me.